# how to run iOS simulator 10.3.1 on Xcode 12.4?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

currently we are developing a flutter app with **flutter SDK 1.20**, we are sticking to version 1.20 due to some outdated packages we use.

after some googling we found that we still can open a debugging session on **iOS simulators 10.3.1**,

we are using **Xcode 12.4** and when we try to add a new simulator and try to download a new OS version, we downloaded iOS simulator 10.3.1 and its added in `Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes` as `iOS 10.3.simruntime`

[image]

but unfortunately its not appearing when we choose to install an OS version on a new iOS simulator.

all we can choose are these simulators only...but **10.3.1** not showing:

[image]

how can we choose iOS simulator 10.3.1?

Comment: should be under the `download more simulator runtimes...` option

Comment: When i choose download more simulators, it open a menu that i choose to download from, 10.3.1 is already downloaded, but not showing in OS version as shown in above images

Answer (score 0):

did you somehow fix this problem?
Regards